# How to handle errors in sql requests

Tags: go

I'm working on a project using Go.

I'm trying to validate a user's session by querying the Postgres database. When I get a match, I want to return true, when I don't, I want to return false.

The issue is, when I don't have a match, my program instead throws errors. I am not sure how to catch these errors in Go yet, or if there is a far smarter approach to how I'm running my query.

```
func confirmUser(userID string, session string) bool {
    sqlStatement := `SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN user_sessions s ON u.id = s.userid WHERE u.id = $1 AND s.session = $2`
    id := 0
    err := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, userID, session).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return false
    }
    fmt.Println("Found:", id)
    return true
}
```

My db variable is a global because I'm using it in plenty of places. I think the issue is coming from the `.Scan()` call, but I'm not sure a better way to go about this. In PHP I'd check if the request was sent successfully, then check the number of rows returned. I'm not sure how to do the equivalent in Go yet.

Comment: You usually check whether the `err` is `sql.ErrNoRows` which means that no row that satisfies the query and its optional where clause exists in the db. As an alternative you could use `SELECT EXISTS( ... )` instead of `SELECT id ...` to have the query always result in a boolean value (unless it's an invalid query) regardless of whether or not the record exists in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`panic()` exits the program. In your example `return false` is never reached. In this case you can `log.Println(err)` and then `return false`. But honestly in a go function like this it is good practice to return a bool and and error. Errors like connection failed, sql errors, est can be returned from your database and needs to be handeled.

```
func confirmUser(userID string, session string) (error, bool) {

    sqlStatement := `SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN user_sessions s ON u.id = s.userid WHERE u.id = $1 AND s.session = $2`
    id := 0
    err := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, userID, session).Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        // if no rows there is no session
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
           return nil, false
        }
        // an error other than no rows was returned, return with error
        return err, false
    }
    fmt.Println("Found:", id)
    return nil, true
}
```

On your function that calls `confirmUser` call your function like this

```
err, valid := confirmUser("myuserid", "sessionstring")
if err != nil {
    return err.Error()
}

if !valid (
    return "user not valid"
}

// user is valid go on
```

Answer (score 0):

you test the returned error value against `sql.ErrNoRows` https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-variables

I also suggest to evaluate client side session storage https://github.com/gorilla/sessions#sessions